# What is the purpose of `set` keyword in Capistrano? (Edited)

Tags: capistrano

```
set :user, "admin"
```

From what I can understand, `set` is a keyword, and it is being used to initialize the `user` variable with `admin` as its value.

Comment: `set` is not a keyword in Ruby. `set :user, "admin"` calls the `set` method with two arguments, the symbol `:user` and the string `"admin"`. What the `set` method does depends on its specific implementation. Can you provide more context? Where did you find this method call? Do you use a specific gem?

Comment: @spickerman if I were to hazard a guess I would say this is `capistrano` (it looks a lot like their DSL) although `whenever` uses a similar syntax I have never seen `set :user` in a `schedule.rb`

Comment: @spickermann it is ```capistrano```

Comment: Your question is unclear. There is no `set` keyword in Ruby. There is no `user` variable in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Capistrano configuration

```
set :user, "admin"
```

sets the `user` variable to the `"admin"` value. See: [Configuration > Access](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/getting-started/configuration/)

The [Properties](https://capistranorb.com/documentation/advanced-features/properties/) page tells you that the `user` variable defines *"the name of the SSH user for the server"*.